# How to save the checkbox state? - android

Tags: java, android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

Ya there are plenty of questions and answers about this stuff in the net but i just can't figure out how to save the checkbox state using sharedpreference. Someone just help me with the coding part which i was not able to do.

```
ch = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

    ch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(ch.isChecked())
                {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uncheck", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }}
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create SharedPrefrences and Add value using `.putBoolean()`

```
 if(ch.isChecked()){             

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFRENCES_NAME, 0);
    settings.edit().putBoolean("check",true).commit();

}
```

- [See here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: did but when i close and open the activity its not checked. what should i do in onstop, onresume, etc?

Comment: see this tuts http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 2):

I think answer you already knew, let me clear your way,

- make a boolean field in table
- set its value true when CheckBox is checked else false

Next time when you are loading the activity, just read the field value and set Checkbox's status accordingly.

Comment: table? He was talking about SharedPreferences.

Comment: @WarrenFaith, my bad, i read the question title and answer it in hurry

Answer (score 1):

```
if(ch.isChecked())
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    preferences.edit().putBoolean("checked", True).commit();
}
```

Comment: code only answers are not welcome. Please add some details to it.